# How to access an index inside an foreach

Tags: php

I need to check if there is a 'CodProduto', so i did:

```
foreach ($movimentos['CodProduto'] as $value){}
```

It will run all CodProduto and If it exists i need to do a if inside the foreach to check 2 others fields:

```
if (!$movimentos['Percentagem'] && !$movimentos['Valor'] {...}
```

My problem is that i dont know how to access the `$movimentos['Percentagem']` and `!movimentos['Valor']` items/index or sub-index i dont know how to call it.

$movimentos['Valor'] is an array and i dont know how to check his items at same time as i check $movimentos['Percentagem']

i know there is `$movimentos['Valor'][$i]` in for but how can i do it in for each? is it possible?
[image]

Comment: Create a counter variable and increment it each iteration, use `array_search` (Returns the index of the first matching result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach` allows you to specify a variable to get the index:

```
foreach ($movimentos['CodProduto'] as $index => $value) {
    if (!$movimentos['Percentagem'][$index] && !$movimentos['Valor'][$index]) {...}
}
```

However, it's usually easier if you put all the related data in a single array, rather than in separate arrays. So instead of

```
$movimentos = [
    "CodProduto" => [...],
    "Percentagem" => [...],
    "Valor" => [...],
    "ProdutoDesignaceo" => [...]
];
```

do it like this:

```
$movimentos = [
    ["CodProduto" => 1, "Percentagem" => 1, "Valor" => 2, "ProdutoDesignaceo" => "..."],
    ["CodProduto" => 2, "Percentagem" => 3, "Valor" => 4, "ProdutoDesignaceo" => "..."],
    ...
];
```

Then your loop would be like:

```
foreach ($movimentos as $m) {
    if (!$m['Percentagem'] && !$m['Valor']) {...}
}
```

Comment: the $index did it for me. I know this is not the best way to pass objects, but it aint my code, im picking some 1's work :< This object comes from JS by ajax. Thanks dude really apreace it!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
foreach ($movimentos['CodProduto'] as $index => $value) {
  echo $index
}
```

Comment: My problem is accessing ``$movimentos['Valor']`` index inside that foreach Not ``'CodProduto'`` index.

Comment: Can you explain that further? Which parts should be tried, and why?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the items and get the Index for each item.
Use this index (`$i`) to access the values from the other arrays while you iterate over the CodProduto sub-array.

```php
foreach ($movimentos['CodProduto'] as $i => $value) {
    $percentagem = $movimentos['Percentagem'][$i];
    $valor = $movimentos['Valor'][$i];
    // Do anything you like with these values here
    // E.g.
    if (!$percentagem && !$valor) {
       // ...
    }
}
```